# Как "нарисовать" трапецию со скругленными углами на CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Собственно вопрос, как "нарисовать" такую трапецию как на рисунке? В инете есть образцы создания трапеции на CSS, но когда я задаю ей `border-radius: 15px` скругляются нижние углы, а необходимо верхние.

[image: трапеция]

Код трапеции:

```css
.block {
  width: 70px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid blueviolet;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class=block></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Делаем обводку псевдоэлементом с `transform: rotateX(40deg)` — таким образом получаем трапецию. Задаем ей `border-radius` только для верхних углов.
2. `transform-origin: 50% 100%` для того, чтобы вращение было вокруг нижней границы.
3. Добавляем `.element` перспективу. Этим свойством в связке с `transform` регулируем угол наклона трапеции.
4. Добавляем остальные стили тексту, чтобы он был сверху псевдоэлемента и находился по центру трапеции (опционально).

```css
.element {
  perspective: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}

.element:before {
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: rotateX(40deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.element__text {
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="element__text">
    Text inside element
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: .5em;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: #009ff0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5) inset;
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(1deg);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Projects</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант со `skew`

```css
#trapezoid{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
}

#trapezoid:before, #trapezoid:after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#trapezoid:before{
    left: -30px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-10deg);
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
}

#trapezoid:after{
    right: -30px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(10deg);
    transform: skewX(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div id=trapezoid></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то есть и такое:

```
border-top-left-radius
border-top-right-radius
```

Comment: .block:{width: 70px;
    height: 0;

    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid blueviolet;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;

    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:15px;} Оно не работает. эти стороны transparent

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/144782)

Comment: @Vadizar согласен. Что мне делать с моей лабудой? Удалить?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, не удалите, просто дополните ваш ответ.

Comment: Я перечитал вопрос, мой отвкт не работает